# gradle is not resolving any new dependencies in android studio

Tags: android

I am making an Intro for my app.So after some research i had got an github project which is used to make cool intros.It requires following dependencies :

```
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
```

when I compile it with gradle it gives me following errors:

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0
```

I have done some research on internet but anything didn't worked out.

here is my `build.gradle(Module:app)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.adarsh.testapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
} 

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
}
```

and here is my `build.gradle(project:testapp)`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Check your connection. Any firewall or proxy that may block you?

Comment: Have you enabled offline work?

Comment: @GKTHEBOSS no it is disabled

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by just adding `mavenCentral()` in repositories in `build.gradle`.